# Reusing Java classes in multiple namespaces with JAXB like in ASP.NET

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, cxf

I have existing ASP.NET SOAP webservices, several of them, which have different namespaces but they use same objects in each of them. In ASP.NET the namespace is specified only in method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://inqmy.com/soapdispatcher/rpc/bcbici/IciEventBean", 
RequestNamespace="urn:IciEventInterface", 
ResponseNamespace="urn:IciEventInterface",
Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("response")]
        public ICI.userChangedResponseResponse userChanged(
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(IsNullable=true)] 
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item")] 
            string[] appIds, 
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("user", IsNullable=true)] 
            ICI.iciUser user1) {
            oii.Log(LogLevel.TRC, "userChanged: {0}  workmode={1}", 
                user1.userId, user1.currentWorkmode.description);
            return new ICI.userChangedResponseResponse();
        }
```

The complex class ICI.iciUser itself does not have any namespace configuration.
This works nicely and it is very simple.

Then I generated Apache CXF client and server in Java, and now all classes are locked to certain namespace. I have several copies of this same IciUser class, each having package-info.java that has different namespace.
I have not managed to find out a way to use only single IciUser class like in .NET.
I can't make a base class and inherit child classes in different packages, because the object is complex, also the properties of class are generated in each package.
Using interface does not work because JAXB does not support it.

The generated Java code has namespace also defined in the method, but this is not enough for JAXB unmarshalling to work.
I tried moving IciUser to another package which wouldn't have any namespace configured, but it didn't work.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://wicom.com/ws/OII/IciUser/", name = "IciEventServiceSoap")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface IciEventServiceSoap {

    @WebMethod(action = "http://inqmy.com/soapdispatcher/rpc/bcbici/IciEventBean")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "userChanged", targetNamespace = "urn:IciEventInterface", className = "com.example.application.ici.event.UserChanged")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "userChangedResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:IciEventInterface", className = "com.example.application.ici.event.UserChangedResponse")
    @WebResult(name = "response", targetNamespace = "urn:IciEventInterface")
    UserChangedResponseResponse userChanged(

            @WebParam(name = "appIds", targetNamespace = "urn:IciEventInterface")
                    ArrayOfString appIds,
            @WebParam(name = "user", targetNamespace = "urn:IciEventInterface")
                    IciUser user
    );
...
```

I have started to think that this is not possible in JAXB. I wonder because JAXB can easily use String class in each namespace, why can't I use my own classes same way? Is JAXB fundamentally broken? Is there any way to customize unmarshalling, to make JAXB find the classes, without locking class to some namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make an ugly workaround for the problem. I added XmlAdapter:

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UserAdapter.class)
    protected User user;
```

XmlAdapter is rather simple:

```
public class UserAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, User> {

    private final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
    private final Marshaller marshaller;
    private final Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    public UserAdapter() throws ParserConfigurationException, JAXBException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.application.ici.model");
        marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    }

    @Override
    public User unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        if (v instanceof Element) {
            Element element = (Element) v;
            Element noNamespace = ElementProxy.fixNamespace(element, null);
            JAXBElement<User> unmarshal = unmarshaller.unmarshal(noNamespace, User.class);
            return unmarshal.getValue();
        }
        return (User) unmarshaller.unmarshal((Node)v);
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(User user) throws Exception {
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        Element root = document.createElement("user");
        marshaller.marshal(user, root);
        return root.getFirstChild();
    }
}
```

The trick is in ElementProxy class, where I patch Element to return null namespace, also for all subitems recursively:

```
class ElementProxy implements Element {

    private final Element element;
    private final String namespace;

    public ElementProxy(Element element, String namespace) {
        this.element = element;
        this.namespace = namespace;
    }

    static public Element fixNamespace(Element element, String namespace) {
        if (!Objects.equals(namespace, element.getNamespaceURI())) {
            return new ElementProxy(element, namespace);
        }
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI() {
        return namespace;
    }

    @Override
    public NodeList getChildNodes() {
        NodeList list = element.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            if (!Objects.equals(namespace, node.getNamespaceURI())) {
                return new NodeList() {
                    @Override
                    public Node item(int index) {
                        Node node1 = list.item(index);
                        if (node1 instanceof Element) {
                            return fixNamespace((Element) node1, namespace);
                        }
                        return node1;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getLength() {
                        return list.getLength();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
...
```

So it is quite ugly, I wish that there was some annotation to make class to work in all namespaces while JAXB is unmarshalling.